# Advance CSV reader to parsing string in linux

Tags: linux, csv

here is an example CSV data:

```
",,",aaa,
,ss,
,,""""",,,"""""
,,`test`
```

the context of csv would like this

[image]

how could I parse text in the column correctly?

Comment: what's the goal of your parsing? what's the environment you would like to use? what's the kind of app or code you would like to use?

Comment: to grep the correct column value in Linux shellcode, for example, when I search B is null, it would echo "",,,"" and `test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from a proper CSV input file like this

```
",,",aaa,
,ss,
,,""""",,,"""""
,,`test`
```

that in a formatted view is

```
+----+-----+---------+
| 1  | 2   | 3       |
+----+-----+---------+
| ,, | aaa | -       |
| -  | ss  | -       |
| -  | -   | "",,,"" |
| -  | -   | `test`  |
+----+-----+---------+
```

you can use Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller). To filter in example the third column values where the second is null, you can write

```
mlr --csv -N filter '$2==""' then cut -f 3 input.csv
```

to obtain

```
""""",,,"""""
`test`
```

The formatted output is

```
+---------+
| 3       |
+---------+
| "",,,"" |
| `test`  |
+---------+
```

Comment: @HsuAmanda please it the tool will work for you, please choose my reply as the right reply